# von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a subset of $B(\mathcal{H})$ (the space of bounded linear operators) such that $M'$ is a von Neumann algebra.

As we know if $M$ is invariant under involution, then $M'$ is a von Neumann algebra. My question is about the converse of it. Is $M$ invariant under $*$-operation, if $M'$ is a von Neumann algebra?

Comment: What about $M=\{\lambda I\}$, where $\lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Aweygan, Since $M=\{\lambda I\}_{\lambda\in \Bbb C - \Bbb R}$ is invariant under involution, $M'$ is a von Neumann algebra.

Comment: No, not $M=\{\lambda I:\lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R\}$, I mean fix some $\lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R$, and put $M=\{\lambda I\}$.  In this case $M'=B(\mathcal H)$, but $M$ is not closed under involution

Comment: @Aweygan But it is not my question. I need to prove or give a counterexample for the convers

Comment: @Aweygan Thanks. it is a nice example. Would you please give me a non proper example?

Comment: What do you mean by non proper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix some $T\in B(\mathcal H)$ that is normal but not self-adjoint, and put $M=\{T\}$.  Then $M'$ is a von Neumann algebra, but $M$ is not self-adjoint.